# Use Google Tag Manager to fire an URL with custom parameters when triggered

Tags: google-tag-manager

When someone visits my site, I'd like Google Tag Manager to fire an URL in the background that sends information about the visit to my affiliate network.

For instance: https://mytrackingsoftware.com/c23r42e43223?utm_source={source}&utm_medium={medium}&some_parameter{parameter}

Let's assume I already have those parameters set as variables in GTM. How can I set GTM up to do the above and (hopefully easily) use the paramters already known to GTM?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. We don't have enough information here. What sort of call do you need to make? Is it a web service call, or do you just need to open the target URL in the client browser? Either way it sounds as if you might need to use some GTM custom Javascript here, using your existing variables, but you'll have to experiment to see whether GTM realistically lets you run the necessary functionality at all, and certainly if it lets you do it without your starting to have timing problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom image tag in GTM, set it to trigger on the page that you want. The "image url" field is where you want to do your request. Like so:

[image]